# How to retrieve data from cloud (iothub)using mqtt in java

Tags: java, azure, azure-eventhub, azure-iot-hub

I am new to IoTHub. I have successfully sent messages to IOT hub (D2C) using python.The protocol we used is mqtt.We are trying to retrieve data from cloud(IOT hub) using java,but could not able to find out a proper  way to recieve message from the cloud..My doubt is whether we can read messages from IOT Hub directly or we need to redirect the incoming messages to an event hub to retrieve the message.

Also I tried to read messages from iothub in java simultaneously while sending data to cloud,but I got the error as follows..(Lost connection to the server. Reconnecting 0 time.)

I use this code to read data from iothub,

```
import com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.DeviceClient;
import com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.IotHubMessageResult;
import com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.Message;
import com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.MessageCallback;
import com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.IotHubClientProtocol;
import com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.service.sdk.IotHubServiceClientProtocol;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
public class Kafkareception {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            String connString = "HostName=";
            IotHubClientProtocol protocol = IotHubClientProtocol.MQTT;
            DeviceClient client = new DeviceClient(connString, protocol);

            MessageCallback callback = new AppMessageCallback();
            client.setMessageCallback(callback, null);
            client.open();
        } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Kafkareception.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private static class AppMessageCallback implements MessageCallback {

        public IotHubMessageResult execute(Message msg, Object context) {
            System.out.println(new String(msg.getBytes(), Message.DEFAULT_IOTHUB_MESSAGE_CHARSET) + "Received message from hub: ");

            return IotHubMessageResult.COMPLETE;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the data from iothub.We can use the code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.*;

import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.time.*;
import java.util.function.*;

public class Datafetch {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        EventHubClient client0 = receiveMessages("0");
        EventHubClient client1 = receiveMessages("1");
        System.out.println("Press ENTER to exit.");
        System.in.read();
        try {
            client0.closeSync();
            client1.closeSync();
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (ServiceBusException sbe) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

private static EventHubClient receiveMessages(final String partitionId) {

        String connStr = "Endpoint={youreventhubcompatibleendpoint};EntityPath={youreventhubcompatiblename};SharedAccessKeyName=iothubowner;SharedAccessKey={youriothubkey}";
        EventHubClient client = null;
        try {
            client = EventHubClient.createFromConnectionStringSync(connStr);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to create client: " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        try {
            client.createReceiver(
                    EventHubClient.DEFAULT_CONSUMER_GROUP_NAME,
                    partitionId,
                    Instant.now()).thenAccept(new Consumer<PartitionReceiver>() {
                        public void accept(PartitionReceiver receiver) {
                            System.out.println("** Created receiver on partition " + partitionId);
                            try {
                                while (true) {
                                    Iterable<EventData> receivedEvents = receiver.receive(100).get();
                                    System.out.println(receivedEvents);
                                    int batchSize = 0;
                                    if (receivedEvents != null) {
                                        for (EventData receivedEvent : receivedEvents) {
                                            System.out.println(String.format("Offset: %s, SeqNo: %s, EnqueueTime: %s",
                                                    receivedEvent.getSystemProperties().getOffset(),
                                                    receivedEvent.getSystemProperties().getSequenceNumber(),
                                                    receivedEvent.getSystemProperties().getEnqueuedTime()));
                                            System.out.println(String.format("| Device ID: %s", receivedEvent.getSystemProperties().getClass()));
                                            System.out.println(String.format("| Message Payload: %s", new String(receivedEvent.getBody(),
                                                    Charset.defaultCharset())));
                                            batchSize++;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    System.out.println(String.format("Partition: %s, ReceivedBatch Size: %s", partitionId, batchSize));
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                System.out.println("Failed to receive messages: " + e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to create receiver: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return client;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From information you provided, you may tried to setup two active connections of one device to Azure IoT Hub using `DeviceClient`: one is sending D2C messages and one is "*reading data from iothub*". You get the error maybe because:

> IoT Hub only supports one active MQTT connection per device. Any new
>   MQTT connection on behalf of the same device ID causes IoT Hub to drop
>   the existing connection.

Ref:[Communicate with your IoT hub using the MQTT protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support).

If you want to receive D2C message that sent to Azure IoT Hub you can [use Event Hub-compatible endpoint(Java)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-java-java-getstarted#receive-device-to-cloud-messages). No need to redirect the incoming messages to an event hub by yourself.

> IoT Hub exposes the messages/events built-in endpoint for your
>   back-end services to read the device-to-cloud messages received by
>   your hub. This endpoint is Event Hub-compatible, which enables you to
>   use any of the mechanisms the Event Hubs service supports for reading
>   messages.

Ref: [Understand Azure IoT Hub messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messaging#read-device-to-cloud-messages) and [IoT Hub endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-endpoints).

Comment: So we cant read data from iothub simultaneously when data sending to iothub. So the data is redirecting to eventhub,then from evebt hub we can read the data using event hub endpoint.Is it like that

Comment: Yes i tried this link  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-java-java-getstarted#receive-device-to-cloud-messages already. I got null when i use this code   Iterable<EventData> receivedEvents = receiver.receive(100).get();

Comment: Can you receive these D2C messages in [Device Explorer](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/master/tools/DeviceExplorer#monitor-device-to-cloud-events)?

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue of  **Lost connection to the server. Reconnection attempt** error